# Get cookie from Next.js CTX when submit data

Tags: cookies, authorization, token, next.js

I am working on Next.js Project and facing an issue with the cookie when submitting. My cookie holds an authorization token. By the following way, I get a token from `CTX` using `getInitialProps` when page load. But, `CTX` is not working when I submit the form. What is the solution, please.

```
const Page = () => {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // I need ctx here when it holds token
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click Here</button>
  );
}

Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx);

  return {};
}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return the `ctx` object (or part of it) from getInitialProps such that your Page accepts it as an argument. Please note it is no longer recommended to use getInitialProps.

Snippet:

```js
const Page = ({ctx}) => { 
    const handleSubmit = () => { 
      console.log(ctx); // should be outputted correctly. 
    }

   return ( 
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click Here</button> 
    ); 
} 

Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => { 
  console.log(ctx); 
  return {ctx};
 } 

export default Page;
```